# JavaScript - I can't save the value of a variable after a loop

Tags: javascript, slider

I want to save the value of a variable in a loop and continue to use it, but I don’t know how to do it

```
function slide(){   
    var picter = document.getElementsByClassName("picter");
    var g=0;
    var c=0;
    for(var i=0;i<picter.length;i++){   
        if(getComputedStyle(picter[i]).opacity == 1){
            picter[g].style.opacity = 0;
            g+=1;
            picter[g].style.opacity = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    //alert(g);
}


<div class="slider" >
    <a class="back arrow" onclick="slide()">Back</a>

    <div class="picterSlider">
        <div class="picter picterLeft">Left</div>
        <div class="picter picterCenter">Center</div>
        <div class="picter picterRight">Right</div>
    </div>

    <a class="next arrow" onclick="slide()">Next</a>
</div>
```

I tried to set to another variable, but it does not work(

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve with this code ? It is not clear to me what variable are you trying to set or what for.

Comment: Which variable exactly do you want to save after the loop? the only variable i see you might want to save is `i`. so clarify which variable in the loop do you want to save after the loop execution.

Comment: I need the variable g to retain its value after the loop and to use the stored value in the next use of the loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set variable as a global variable

```
var picter;
var g=0;
var c=0;
function slide(){   
     = document.getElementsByClassName("picter");

    for(var i=0;i<picter.length;i++){   
        if(getComputedStyle(picter[i]).opacity == 1){
            picter[g].style.opacity = 0;
            g+=1;
            picter[g].style.opacity = 1;
            break;
        }
    }
    //alert(g);
}


<div class="slider" >
    <a class="back arrow" onclick="slide()">Back</a>

    <div class="picterSlider">
        <div class="picter picterLeft">Left</div>
        <div class="picter picterCenter">Center</div>
        <div class="picter picterRight">Right</div>
    </div>

    <a class="next arrow" onclick="slide()">Next</a>
</div>
```

Or you also can save your value of variable into `localstorage`. And everytime you want to use, you can retrive it from `localstograte`

Comment: ahhahah, sorry for such an idiotic question) I'am firsting programmist

Answer (score 0):

I think I see what you're trying to do here, you could have a look on the snippet with the comments and I'd be happy to answer any of your questions if any.

```js
// Define g globally
var g = 0;

function slide(increment) {
  var picter = document.getElementsByClassName("picter");
  var c = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < picter.length; i++) {
    if (getComputedStyle(picter[i]).opacity == 1) {
      picter[g].style.opacity = 0;
      g += increment;
      
      // Make sure g doesn't get below 0
      g = g < 0 ? 0 : g;
      
      // Make sure g doesn't go beyond the last element
      g = g > picter.length - 1 ? picter.length - 1 : g;
      picter[g].style.opacity = 1;
      break;
    }
  }
  
  alert(g);
}
```

```html
<div class="slider">
  <a class="back arrow" onclick="slide(-1)">Back</a>

  <div class="picterSlider">
    <div class="picter picterLeft">Left</div>
    <div class="picter picterCenter">Center</div>
    <div class="picter picterRight">Right</div>
  </div>

  <a class="next arrow" onclick="slide(1)">Next</a>
</div>
```